# Зайти на сайт через ISP

Tags: ispmanager

Могу ли я зайти на сайт не по домену, а по ссылке? Например http://1.2.3.4:80/www/mysite.ru

Comment: А что мешает? У вас возникли проблемы какие-то ?

Comment: Ну пишет 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Как правило**, на основе доменного имени в HTTP-запросе вебсервер, обслуживающий несколько сайтов, направляет на тот или иной сайт. Этот механизм называется **"виртуальные хосты"**, с его помощью один IP-адрес может обслуживать разные комбинации протоколов и доменных имён (или чего ещё, вроде IP-адреса клиента) , как если бы это были разные хосты. Но реально машина всего одна, потому хосты виртуальные.

Соответственно, если виртуальный хост вашего сайта получает запросы только с определённым доменным именем, если его не указать, запросы уйдут не туда. И не факт, что их там ждут. Скажем, если доменное имя опустить совсем, с высокой вероятностью запросы уйдут на "виртуальный хост по умолчанию", где обычно страничка владельцев самой машины. Или заглушка с ошибкой.

Если нет, то способ может быть. Зависит от конфигурации вашего вебсервера.